# How to ignore Observable .interval() on component first load in Angular 2

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I have a simple instance where i create an observable that acts as a countdown timer by using a interval of 1000ms. Works great but my issue is it wont render the component until after the interval time, so if its 1000ms or 10000ms it takes that load to do first paint.

Is there a way i can skip interval on initial load? Here's what i currently have:

```
this.countDown = Observable
  .interval(1000)
  .map(res=>{ 

    /** I have some logic here. **/

  })
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Observable.timer`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-timer) instead that takes as the first argument the initial delay:

```
Observable.timer(0, 1000)
    .whatever()
```

Comment: Works as it should! The one thing about rxjs is the knowledge base is so large it's hard to find gems like these in the wild. Thanks Martin works exactly how i need!

Comment: @22Ryann I know that from my own experience :).